# How to make the Gnome Control Center (Settings) left panel background colors on hover more obvious in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, system-settings, accessibility, gnome-control-center

If you look at the left pane there are menu item separators, a selected color, hover colors, and "zebra striping" of all unselected rows.  When I hover over a white zebra-striped row it practically matches the other gray unselected zebra-striped rows.

This is a usability/accessibility issue which affects me and probably some other users.

[image: settings dialog]

How can I make it more clear which row is being "hovered" over?

Comment: Thanks for the reword.  The LP bug that is referenced by this snippet of CSS dates back quite a long time to nearly 2012.  Given that Ubuntu wasn't shipping with Gnome 3 back then it's likely that it couldn't have been foreseen to have consequences years down the line if it were retained.  This is a wide-reaching, non-app specific selector that could easily impact multiple applications whether intentional or not.  Also, Aidwata doesn't exhibit this same zebra striping nor do any other themes I've perused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using GTKInspector I was able to zero in on the "zebra striping" and track it down to the following lines for the Ambiance theme (which I use and like) in */usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/gtk-widgets.css*:

```
.view row:nth-child(odd):not(:selected) {  
    /* zebra stripping, see LP#945430 */  
    background-color: shade (@base_color, 0.965);
```

Having a quick Google at [LP#945430](https://bugs.launchpad.net/light-themes/+bug/945430) I was able to see that this was intended to be a long-ago fix for a lack of readability of the long lists of songs in Rhythmbox.  Adding the zebra striping was to improve legibility according to the report.  I can report that it doesn't do anything for Rhythmbox under Ambiance in Ubuntu 18.04 and according to the report is still "broken" wrt Rhythmbox.

So, assuming now that this is quite possibly an unintended consequence, I set out to fix the left panel styling.  Removing the above CSS snippet "fixed" this issue.

[image]